# not able to change node version after doing npm install in mac

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

I was using node versions 10.x.x and 12.x.x using nvm before.
Then i installed new node version using the command

```
npm install -g node@14. 
and also installed new npm version using the command 
npm install npm@6
```

after doing these if i do   nvm use v10

its still not switching to node version 10

[image]

Comment: Could you try nodejs -v?

Comment: and also `whereis node` to see if you have conflicting dependencies

Answer (score 0):

```
nvm list // apply this first
```

you will see differents options

```
       v10.24.1
       v12.13.0
       v12.22.6
->     v14.13.1
       ...
```

then apply the command to use

```
nvm use v10.24.1
```

in your case:

```
nvm use v10.22.0
```

you need to copy paste completly like,  not just `v10`

Comment: This didnt work

Answer (score 0):

use NVM to switch node versions, you can use the install script directly, restart the shell and start using it like:

```
nvm install <node_version>
```

if you want to get the list of available versions you can:
if you want to see what versions has already been installed:

```
nvm ls or nvm list
or
nvm ls-remote
```

if you want to switch a version try this:

first install your desired version using

```
nvm install vXXXXXX(version number exact)
```

then to switch version

`nvm use <node_version>` # (the version should be already installed using nvm install)

and if you want to set up a default version you can alias it like this:

```
nvm alias default
```